# How to replace line with 3 lines / add 2 before found / add 2 before 1 from end

Tags: command-line, sed

File is:

```
#Welcome to the file
#this is a file and it ends on "exit 0"
#Here are unknown number of lines
exit 0
```

Needs to have these lines one after each other:

```
echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch
```

So it looks like this:

```
#Welcome to the file
#this is a file and it ends on "exit 0"
#Here are unknown number of lines
echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch
exit 0
```

PROBLEMS- command inside command inside command with many Lines `\n`

For now I have command `sed -i 's/exit 0/echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler\necho 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch\nexit 0/gp' /usr/file` but something is wrong in it - it doesn't work.

#### Update 1

"SLASHES" `/` to `\/`: I found the solution for slashes to use `\/` and backslashes `\\`.

So now my command works `sed -i 's/exit 0/echo deadline > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/scheduler\necho 1 > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/iosched\/fifo_batch\nexit 0/' /usr/file`

But it needs to be modified cause now it finds all expressions but how so just that it finds a line having nothing else in it? So it doesn't replace whats in `exit 0` in example files comment.

#### Update 2

At least line starting with `^`: Found to make solution for this file `sed 's/^exit 0/\necho deadline > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/scheduler\necho 1 > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/iosched\/fifo_batch\nexit 0/' /usr/file` but in case text file has lines:

```
exit 0
exit 0 means exiting
```

Then cant use `^` to find line starting with expression.

So best way would be which I can't find how to find exact line containing just expression or find expression line and not all expressions?

#### Update 3

Exact line `^` & `$`: Tuns out `^` limits nothing to be on left side and `$` nothing to be on right side so now working solution for 1. solution is `sed -i 's/^exit 0$/\necho deadline > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/scheduler\necho 1 > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/iosched\/fifo_batch\nexit 0/' /usr/file`

I want to learn at least 3 ways using 1 line commands. How to:

1. replace found line with 3 lines with symbol containing command as mentioned
2. found complete line and not just expression and add 2 lines before found
3. add 2 lines 1 line before end

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Can you show us an example of what an initial and final file each might look like?

Comment: Please ask multiple questions independently, as separate questions.

Comment: Please frame your question **precisely**. It's not clear what "replace found line with 3 lines with symbols" means, since one expects "replace" to have only one corresponding "with" after it, like "replace A with B".

Comment: @Kangarooo - please can you confirm if the answers below resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4):

These might work for you (they all achieve the same thing!):

```
 sed '/^exit 0/i\echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler\necho 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch' file
```

Search for line beginning `exit 0` and insert 2 lines.

Or:

```
 sed '$i\echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler\necho 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch' file
```

Insert 2 lines before last line of file.

Or:

```
 sed '$c\echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler\necho 1 > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch\nexit 0' file
```

Change last line of file to 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

For question 3: I assume you want to add some text between the last and last-but-one line in a file. Additionally, this text consists of 2 lines, but that doesn't matter. `head -n -1` will extract all but the last line, and `tail -n 1` will extract the last line. So one can do

```
head -n -1 file > outputfile
cat file_with_two_line_text >> outputfile
tail -n 1 file >> outputfile
```

This isn't very efficient as it scans 'file' twice, while one needs to scan it only once.